# how to make use of a custom key generator in hibernate by default

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to be able to make use of my own custom id generator in hibernate but without all the messiness of several annotations per entity.

Example:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "XyzIdGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "XyzIdGenerator",
        strategy = "com.mycompany.myapp.id.BigIntegerSequenceGenerator",
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "xyz_id_sequence")
        })
```

That's a lot. I want to set it up where, if hibernate sees "@Id"
it will by default invoke my generator and assign it to the id.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do this is to create a superclass which contains the annotated variables that are shared and make the entities extend it. Example:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class PersistableEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "XyzIdGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "XyzIdGenerator",
            strategy = "com.mycompany.myapp.id.BigIntegerSequenceGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "xyz_id_sequence")
            })
    protected Long id;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Abc extends PersistableEntity {}
```

`@MappedSuperclass` is important here:

> Designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the
>   entities that inherit from it. A mapped superclass has no separate
>   table defined for it.

Comment: Another problem might be that, with all tables using the same sequence generator, there's no overlap of numbers...which can be good, but can cause other problems (such as arbitrarily large index values increasing very quickly).  It can also be more difficult for someone else to maintain since it's less than normal.

Comment: Why not just add an IDE macro to dump all the annotations in and make it quick and easy?

Comment: In fact I haven't use this "pattern" for ids, but for several other fields like creation/delete date, etc. The sequence problem you mentioned is not impossible to fix, though.